# RobotFramework: How to span user keyword's argument definition over multiple lines for better readability

Tags: robotframework

In Robot Framework, if I have a user keyword with long list of arguments, then for better readability I need to split them into multiple lines.

Current keyword:

```
My User Keyword
    [Arguments]    ${arg1}=Default Val1    ${arg2}=Default Val2    ${arg3}=Default Val3
```

The way I want for better readability:

```
My User Keyword
    [Arguments]    ${arg1}=Default Val1    ${arg2}=Default Val2\
    ...    ${arg3}=Default Val3
```

The above form is giving me error (it works in keyword body but not in arguments section). Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the way I was doing was wrong. The correct syntax is without \ at the end,

```
My User Keyword
    [Arguments]    ${arg1}=Sample Val1    ${arg2}=Sample Val2
    ...    ${arg3}=Sample Val3
```

Below section in the user guide explains it,
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#dividing-test-data-to-several-rows